# Embedding Mongoose Web Server in C++

Tags: c++, webserver, mongoose-web-server

I just embedded the Mongoose Web Server into my C++ dll (just a single header and recommended in most of the stack overflow threads) and I have it up and running properly with the very minimal example code.

However, I am having a rough time finding any sort of tutorials, examples, etc. on configuring the very basic necessities of a web server. I need to figure out the following...

1) How to allow directory browsing

2 Is it possible to restrict download speeds on the files?

3) Is it possible to have a dynamic list of IPs addresses allowed to download files?

4) <strike>How to allow the download of specific file extensions (.bz2 in this case)</strike> *ANSWERED*

5) <strike>How to bind to a specific IP Address</strike> *ANSWERED*

Most of the information I have found is in regards to using the pre-compiled binary release, so I am a bit stumped right now. Any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) "enable_directory_listing"  option

2) <strike>Not built into Mongoose (at least not the version I have, which is about 6 months old).</strike> [EDIT:] Newer versions of Mongoose support [throttling](https://github.com/valenok/mongoose/blob/master/UserManual.md#throttle) download speed.  From the manual...

> Limit download speed for clients. throttle is a comma-separated list
>   of key=value pairs, where key could be:
>
> ```
> *                   limit speed for all connections
> x.x.x.x/mask        limit speed for specified subnet
> uri_prefix_pattern  limit speed for given URIs
> ```
>
> The value is a floating-point number of bytes per second, optionally
>   followed by a k or m character, meaning kilobytes and megabytes
>   respectively. A limit of 0 means unlimited rate. The last matching
>   rule wins. Examples:
>
> ```
> *=1k,10.0.0.0/8=0   limit all accesses to 1 kilobyte per second,
>                     but give connections from 10.0.0.0/8 subnet
>                     unlimited speed
>
> /downloads/=5k      limit accesses to all URIs in `/downloads/` to
>                     5 kilobytes per secods. All other accesses are unlimited
> ```

3) "access_control_list" option.  In the code `accept_new_connection` calls `check_acl` that compares the client's IP to a list of IPs to accept and/or ignore. From the manual...

> Specify access control list (ACL). ACL is a comma separated list of IP
>   subnets, each subnet is prepended by '-' or '+' sign. Plus means
>   allow, minus means deny. If subnet mask is omitted, like "-1.2.3.4",
>   then it means single IP address. Mask may vary from 0 to 32 inclusive.
>   On each request, full list is traversed, and last match wins. Default
>   setting is to allow all. For example, to allow only 192.168/16 subnet
>   to connect, run "mongoose
>   -0.0.0.0/0,+192.168/16".  Default: ""

http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/wiki/MongooseManual

Answer (score 2):

Of course as soon as I give up and post, I find most of the answers were right in front of my face. Here is the options for them...

```
const char *options[] =
{
    "document_root", "C:/",
    "listening_ports", "127.0.0.1:8080",
    "extra_mime_types", ".bz2=plain/text",
    NULL
};
```

However, I am still not sure how to make enable directory browsing. Right now, my callback function is just the basic one out of the example (as seen below). What would I need to do to get it so the files are listed?

```
static void *callback(enum mg_event event, struct mg_connection *conn, const struct mg_request_info *request_info)
{
    if (event == MG_NEW_REQUEST)
    {
        // Echo requested URI back to the client
        mg_printf(conn, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
            "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
            "%s", request_info->uri);

        return "";  // Mark as processed
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your callback is called for each request, including the directory request, and marks it as processed by returning non-NULL. You need to return NULL if a directory has been requested. Mongoose then shows the directory, unless "enable_directory_listing" option is set to "no". In a simplest case,
    if (!strcmp(request_info->uri, "/")) {
      return NULL;
    }